# JavaScript to change CSS dynamically when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change some css properties when scrolling.
This worked with jQuery and I can't make it work using JavaScript.

This is the function that reads and set CSS properties:

```
function parallel_height_js(){
  let scroll_top = window.scrollY;
  console.log('scroll top = ',scroll_top)
  let header_height = document.getElementsByClassName("sample-header-section")[0].clientHeight;
  console.log('Header height = ',header_height)
  document.getElementsByClassName("text-section")[0].style.marginTop = header_height;
  console.log('text margin top = ',document.getElementsByClassName("text-section")[0].style.marginTop)
  document.getElementsByClassName("sample-header")[0].style.height = header_height - scroll_top;
  console.log('header height = ',document.getElementsByClassName("sample-header")[0].style.height)
}
```

Afterwards, I execute the following to execute the function at scrolling or resizing:

```
parallel_height_js();

window.onscroll = parallel_height_js;
window.onresize = parallel_height_js;
```

In the browser console I get this from console.log:

```
scroll top =  8
Header height =  517
text margin top =  
header height =
```

I checked that I am accessing the right elements when trying to set the CSS value, but this CSS value is not changing.

Comment: Can't test since you haven't provided an [mre], but I think you just forgot to add `px`: `...style.marginTop = header_height + 'px'`

Comment: Why are you expecting these to have values?   Is it defined in your css?  On your html?   (we don't know as you didn't include those, see [mcve]).   If it's not defined, it will be automatic and the value will be `''`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes, you were right, Thank you. I posted HTML in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I didn't add 'px' string when setting new CSS values.
So, the js code would be:

```
import './style.css'

function parallel_height_js(){
  let scroll_top = window.scrollY;
  let header_height = document.getElementsByClassName("sample-header-section")[0].clientHeight;
  document.getElementsByClassName("text-section")[0].style.marginTop = header_height+'px';
  document.getElementsByClassName("sample-header")[0].style.height = (header_height - scroll_top)+'px';
}
parallel_height_js();

window.onscroll = parallel_height_js;
window.onresize = parallel_height_js;
```

HTML:

```
<header>
        <div class="sample-header">
          <div class="...">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
            <label for="menu"></label>
            <div class="menu-content">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a> </li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sample-header-section">
            <h1>...</h1>
            <h2>...</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```